# Organizing VBA Project

Tags: vba, ide

I am maintaining a large MS Access Project. Over time the number of modules and classes has grown, at this moment it contains 90 modules. More and more time do I spend searching for a specific class in the list. (I know about Shift+F2 :))

Is there any way to organize the list of modules in the VBA editor, i.e. some kind of Addin? My idea would be subfolders in the tree or a filter-as-you-type textbox.

Best regards,
 Torben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all try: MZ-Tools. It has free version for MS Access. [HomePage](http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx)

It's a toolkit that help maintain access project in many aspects: create automatic documentation; create, modify and maintain procedures, functions and properties etc.

Answer (score 0):

Develop a logical naming system. You can't get a tree per-se, but you can name things in a way that they are easier to find.

```
Module 1: A_systemtools
module 2: __systemtools_a
module 3: B_programitems
etc...
```